# firefox: display RSS feed in firefox as text

Tags: firefox, xml, rss, feed

In chrome, when I go to RSS feed, it displays it simply as XML/text:

https://doomberg.substack.com/feed

In firefox, it just downloads the file. When I change the settings in preferences: Always ask

then it offers to download, or open in external application.

How can I simply display it "inline" in firefox, as if it was plain text?

I am using Firefox 102.6 on Debian 10

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: find an RSS feed reader extension you like and add that to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an extension that allows direct *display* of RSS feeds as HTML, rather than downloading, such as [rss.html](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rss-html/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search).
2. Click on the feed, such as your link, https://doomberg.substack.com/feed.
3. Right-click on the page and elect *Inspect*.

The RSS feed will be displayed as nicely-formatted **text**. BTW, click on the triangles to expand or close a section... makes for easy reading.

[image: rss.html]

Of course, use care for security when selecting an extension, and disable it when not needed, since an extension may have undesired access to data.

Comment: thank you, but can't I do this without extension? After all, I just want to display simple plaintext format.